# Algebra question concerning about in terms.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $K=\dfrac{x}{3}$ and $x \neq 0$ , what does $3x$ equal in terms of $K$?
Does this mean you put everything equal to $K$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If $K=\dfrac{x}{3}$ and $x \neq 0$ , what does $3x$ equal in terms of $K$?

We know

1. $\;K = \dfrac x3\;$ and that
2. $x \neq 0$

So we want to first solve for $x$. Using $(1)$: $$K = \frac x3 \;\;\iff \;\; 3K = 3\cdot \frac x3  \;\; \iff 3K = x \;\; \iff \;\;x = 3K$$

Now, we determine the value of $3x$, given $\;\color{blue}{\bf x = 3K}$:

$$3\color{blue}{\bf x} = 3(\color{blue}{\bf 3K}) = (3\cdot 3) K = 9K.$$

Comment: Thanks I understand this more now!

Comment: You're welcome, Little Jon!

Answer (score 3):

If you want $3x$ in terms of $K$, we have:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
K=\dfrac{x}{3}\\
3K=3\dfrac{x}{3}=x\\
3^2K=3x
\end{array}
$$
Just multiply both sides of the equation $K=\dfrac{x}{3}$ by $9$ (that is, by 3 two times) to get $3x=9K$

Comment: Where did you get 9?

Comment: I've edited my answer so you can see.